# OGNL expression in PingFederate to get the ACSIdx

Tags: pingfederate

Is that possible to get the ACSIdx value through OGNL expression ?
I have many ACS in one connection and need to do some action based on ACSIdx value.
I tried using #this.get("ACSIdx") which didnt work.

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot get the ACSidx in an OGNL expression in PingFederate.